# Reading html data from a text file in PHP and AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have this text file filled with some html code;

```
<span>test</span><p>welcome</p>
<span>Guest</span><p><img class="insertedImage" src="/dynamictemplate/uploads/temp/167-5-IMG_0755.JPG" width="80" height="80"/></p>
```

I'm reading this html data into a div element, however when I try to add a click event to the 'img' tag it's not working. I know it reads the the file correctly because if I add a css targeting the '.insertedImage' it works fine, but when I try to add a click event its not doing anything.

```
$('.insertedImage').click(function() 
{
  alert("clicked");
});
```

Anyone has an idea about what causing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your content loading dynamically and then your event is not fired.

Then try this event [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

In your case

```
$(".insertedImage").on("click",  function(event){
    alert($(this).text());
});
```

Comment: No it didn't work. in fact for some reason, it broke all my other jquery events.

Comment: @akk kur What jquery version are you using? If < 1.7, you can try using [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) instead of on(), because if IIRC on() was added from 1.7 on

Comment: oh I'm using 1.6.3 I think that's why its not working. I'm gonna try with the 1.7

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap it around $(document).ready()

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.insertedImage').click(function() 
    {
       alert("clicked");
    });
});
```